# Xcode - color of UIImageView in xib/storyboard

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, uistoryboard, xib

At office, I have two different Macs. In one of this when I drag a `UIImageView` in xib/storyboards, this appears light blue like in this image.

[image: UIImageView with light blue background]

but on the other Mac, the `UIImageView` appears brown/sandy.

[image: UIImageView with light brown background]

I can't explain why and can't find a configuration for this.

Now I have Xcode 9, but it was the same with Xcode 8 and 7.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This color depends on the **highlight color** which you can set in **System Preferences/General/Highlight color**.

[image: Highlight color setting inside General]